# Bulk copy filtered rows from one google sheet to another google sheet

Tags: copy, bulk, filtered

I have a spreadsheet where I am able to filter the sheet based on a value on a column.  I can copy the filtered data using isRowHiddenByFilter.  But this does it one row at a time.  I am looking for some input on how I can copy say 200 rows that I obtain after using a filter to be copied to another spreadsheet all at once and not evaluating 200 rows.

This is what I have working:

```
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains("I do NOT 
           plan").build();
ss.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4,criteria);

var nrsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Not Returning");

for (var i = 2; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) 
{
  if(!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) 
  {
    row_data = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    one_arr_nr = row_data.join().split(",");
    nrsheet.appendRow(one_arr_nr);
  }
}
```

This is what I would like to do:
Remove the for loop to evaluate each row and be able to copy what I see on the spreadsheet to be copied to the Not Returning sheet.  Any help on how I can proceed?